# Shortcut for capturing an area into clipboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, screenshot

In Ubuntu there is a cool feature where you can assign a shortcut key to open the screenshot tool to capture an area and copy the image into the clipboard.

On Windows there is the snipping tool. And I know I can open it with a shortcut. But you have to press new, save the image, then find that image. Is there a way or a software that would allow me to do this like Ubuntu handles it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a shortcut in Windows for capturing a selected area after which the image is stored in the clipboard.

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

It darkens the whole screen and gives you a cursor for selecting a rectangular area. After selecting the area the screenshot is taken and stored in the clipboard after which you can easily paste the image. Most chat programs support sending images by simply pasting the image into the chat.

It works really fast. Much better than having to open the snipping tool and do more unnecessary work.

You need to have Windows 10 Creator Update or newer installed for this feature to work. If you don't have it, the Snipping Tool has an option to save new snips to the clipboard.

Comment: Good to know. Could you improve your answer by elaborating a little bit on how that works?

Comment: Improved the answer :D

Comment: It does nothing for me nor I cannot find it in [list of keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts). Could you please quote your source?

Comment: Maybe it's only in the Windows 10 Creators Update: https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-shift-s-new-way-to-take-screenshots-windows-10-creators-update
Will edit the answer to put that in. What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, but I am not at the Creators Update yet.